# Will the memories be cleared when i launch a new kernel/application?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

A general question. 
I wonder if the Global/shared/cache memories and registers are cleared (content set to 0) when i launch a new kernel/application?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to initialize the memory yourself. Neither `__shared__` memory, nor global memory are automatically initialized.(1)

The caches will be "consistent" with whatever is in memory(2).  You need not worry about those.

Registers are not normally accessible from CUDA C/C++ source code, but if you are using inline PTX or some other method, registers are not guaranteed to hold any particular value unless you place it there explicitly.

(1) Constructs like `thrust::device_vector` *will* imply some form of initialization.  So I'm referring to "ordinary CUDA C/C++" here.

(2) "Consistent" for a given cacheline means either:

- the cacheline is marked "invalid"  (or)
- the cacheline is marked "valid" and it accurately represents the contents of whatever memory it is caching.